# XLPagerTabStrip black space

Tags: ios, iphone, xlpagertabstrip

I am using XLPagerTabStrip for getting android tabtool in ios[getting black space like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs5Il.png)  but using this I am getting a black space between view and screen when  I scroll the end point view controller why? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyPagerTabStripName: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    self.containerView.bounces = false // add this line to disable bounce
}
```

or if you want to keep bounce effect, you can set view's `backgroundColor`, like in your image, you can change `backgroundColor` to white.